# React native project not running on android emulator after windows updates

Tags: react-native, android-emulator, windows-update

Yesterday my react native project was running fine and very correctly on my Nexus Android emulator, but after some automatic windows 10 updates I was shocked after rerunning my project and finding out it returns error and can't even open it on the android emulator. I thought the problem could be coming from the project so i created a totally new react native project to test and it turns out even the default react starter project isn't working.[error message screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2bQkq.png)[infos about the project screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hjlvw.png)
Here is the error (screen of cmd line and some info)
Please if anyone could help me i will really appreciate.

Comment: When i run on expo it tells me this "Couldn't start project on Android: Error running adb: Performing Push Install"

Answer (score 0):

Set android SDK path in environment variables in windows

Comment: I don't understand, do you mean adding the sdk path and the ANDROID_HOME variable ? If so I already have all these correctly set up but I have no clue about the problem it keeps showing..